# Any way to use async/await on Compact Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, async-ctp

I'm curious as to whether there will be any way to use the C# `async`/`await` CPS transformation feature with Compact Framework code.  I expect a certain amount of library code will need to be supplied/reimplemented in order to make that happen; if so, where should I look for information on what types/members would need to be provided?

(I'm not looking for a complete task-asynchrony support library here, just enough of a skeleton to be able to use the language feature.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Jon Skeet's [eduasync](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx) series for the library side, but I'm not sure whether the Async CTP compiler update will work for CF development. Last I checked, CF wasn't supported on VS2010, but Async CTP requires VS2010 SP1.

P.S. CF is on the way out, I'm afraid. It's all semi-Silverlight for "device" programming in the future.

Comment: Correct: CF still is not supported on VS2010.

Comment: The grim reality is that I'm rev-locked -- it's a non-negotiable requirement to support existing customer devices with CE 5.0 Webpad/ARMv4i/128MB RAM/2GB SD.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio 2015 to compile to Compact Framework 3.5 by following the instructions below:

- Install the '.NET Compact Framework 3.5 Redistributable';
- Copy files from '*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE*';
- Paste the files at '*C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\CompactFramework*' directory;
- Create a directory named '*RedistList*';
- Create a file named '*FrameworkList.xml*' at '*RedistList*' directory;
- Set the follwing content to the file created:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FileList Redist="Net35-CF" Name=".NET Compact Framework 3.5">
  </FileList>
  ```

Now you can create a **.NET Core Class Library** project on Visual Studio 2015 and target '*net35-cf*' framework.

To use async/await you can use the *System.Threading.Tasks.WindowsCE* package.

An example project can be found at: https://github.com/WindowsCE/System.Collections.Concurrent/tree/08669ca5b45cc5c74c8c225a633828f9e26b5276

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the package and the project above.

Comment: Very curious! Could you tell me if this code can be debugged on device?

Comment: You can if you add a reference to the library compiled on VS2015 in a project created on VS2008.